# Why are there Topology artefacts in Unity, but can`t see in Blender?

Tags: modeling, topology

When i check model in Blender - everything is Ok*
But in Unity, even in PAINT 3D - there are artefacts in model. How can i see it in Blender and anticipate topology errors in Unity?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without more information, but it looks as if you have n-gons in Blender and Unity probably triangulates them automatically and fails at that. You should make sure you don't have n-gons and concave faces in your model - you could simply triangulate the mesh in Blender.

Comment: "*in Blender - everything is Ok*" It isn't, the problem is just hidden away. Looks like you abused booleans and are now paying the price for it. The issues of bad topology become visible in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Apply modifiers and triangulate in Blender, only then export mesh to Unity.

Also, this looks to be mesh made with booleans. Boolean is not going to give you a clean topology. Rather apply boolean and make sure in Blender that the topology is ok.

Comment: Sometimes this is overkill, and simply selecting everything and doing *Mesh > Cleanup > Split Concave Faces* is enough.

Comment: For anyone wondering, it's because Unity (like other game engines) doesn't support N-Gons and automatically triangulates the mesh when imported. But it doesn't do it the same way as Blender, hence the discrepancies.